# Running multiple web sites on a single EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, web-server, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

To cut costs and simplify management, we have been thinking about running multiple web sites on a single Windows EC2 instance.

Is that something you would recommend? what are the pros and cons? Can you recommend the best approach to configure AWS to support this?

Comment: What research have you done so far?

Comment: I have configured successfully a single web server to host multiple sites in IIS using secondary IP addresses and Elastic IP's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Is that something you would recommend?
```

Sure, if it makes sense for your situation.

```
what are the pros and cons?
```

You could save money by hosting multiple websites on one server. One server also acts as a single point of failure. You'll also lose the ability to scale the websites independently.

```
Can you recommend the best approach to configure AWS to support this?
```

There's nothing particularly special about AWS when it comes to hosting multiple websites on the same server. If you'd like to take advantage of Load Balancers (ELBs) and AutoScaling you can research those, however this would depend on what exactly you're trying to achieve and what your requirements are.

Comment: Saving money was the only reason why our manager was considering this. However, i agree that it is not the best approach for auto-scaling sites separately.

Comment: Money shouldn't be the only consideration :) you should think about how likely it is that one of your websites will have a negative affect on the other website(s), and how acceptable that risk is should it eventuate.